# Unwind Segue with Show Segue

Tags: swift, swift2

I understand how to use an unwind segue when you have a button on storyboard to connect to exit. But in my app I am using a push segue to go from a TableViewController to a ViewController. So I have a default "Back" button in my navigation controller. The problem is, the back button does not show up in storyboard so I cannot connect it to the ViewController's Exit unwindSegue method. How do I access the default button in the navigation controller to connect it to the unwind segue in the TableViewController. I am wanting to pass data with the unwind segue or else the default back button would work for navigation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The default back button is default so that's why you don't see it. As I understand it you want to go back directly to your main VC.

Give the push segue an identifier from the identity inspector.

In ViewDidAppear of the TableViewController perform the segue. This will give a back button on the main VC to the other Controller.